expected number of coin tosses to get k heads, not necessarily consecutive
Let's say we have a coin whose probability of heads is $p$, and tail is $1-p$. Define $X_n$ as the number of heads, in any order, on $n$ tosses. Then clearly the probability that on $n$ coin tosses, the probability of getting $k$ heads ($n \geq k$) is:
\begin{equation}
p[ X_n = k ] = \binom nkp^k(1-p)^{n-k}.
\end{equation}
Now the expected number of coin tosses needed to see $k$ heads (not necessarily consecutive) is:
\begin{equation}
E[ X ] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n \cdot \binom nkp^k(1-p)^{n-k}.
\end{equation}
Intuitively, the answer should be $E[X]=k/p$. But how does one go from the expression above to $k/p$?.
Note I'm not asking about $k$ consecutive heads, which is just a Markov chain as seen in https://courses.cit.cornell.edu/info2950_2012sp/mh.pdf.
======================
Per @brian Tung's suggestion, define $A_1$ as the expected number of coin flip to see one head, then we have:
\begin{equation}
A_1 = (1-p)(1+A_1) + p  \implies A_1 = 1/p.
\end{equation}
So by linearity of expectations we have $k \cdot 1/p$.
This is very nice. if someone wants to simplify the binomial expectation I wrote above I'll give it a checkmark.

The expression for the probability that the $k$th head appears on the $n$th toss  should be  $\binom {n-1}{k-1}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ as the final toss must be a head.

@Henry here I'm just asking what's the likelihood of getting $k$ heads in any order. For example, if $n=4$ and $k=2$, then this sequence is ok: $1010$, as is this $1100$, or $0110$, etc.

It's easier to just figure out the time required to see one head, and then multiply by $k$, by linearity of expectation. Unless you want specifically to simplify that summation, I wouldn't go that particular route.

@BrianTung good call updated the question w/ the answer you suggested. If someone knows how to simplify the binomial expectation that'd still be nice though.

Your question is "the expected number of coin tosses needed to see $k$ heads" so presumably you stop when you have seen $k$ heads.  You can see something is going wrong when $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty   \binom nkp^k(1-p)^{n-k} = \frac1p \not =1 = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n \cdot \binom {n-1}{k-1}kp^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ so you do not have a probability distribution.  Multiplying by $n$ and then summing gives $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n \cdot \binom nkp^k(1-p)^{n-k} = \frac{k+1-p}{p^2}$ instead of the desired $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n \cdot \binom {n-1}{k-1}kp^k(1-p)^{n-k} = \frac{k}{p}$.

@Henry i feel like you're making an important point and I'm slightly confused. How di you get $\frac{k+1-p}{p^2}$? Can you write it out in an answer and I'll checkmark it?

$\frac{k}{p}$ is the right answer to "the expected number of coin tosses needed to see $k$ heads".

As for the expected number of tosses to see one head, since the probability that the $n^\text{th}$ toss is needed is $q^{n-1}$, the expected number of tosses is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty q^{n-1}=\frac1{1-q}=\frac1p.$$

Your expression for the expected number of tosses needed to obtain $\ k\ $ heads is incorrect.  If $\ H_k\ $ is the number of the toss on which the $\ k^\text{th}\ $ head appears, then the expected number of tosses needed to see $\ k\ $ heads is
$$
E\big[H_k\big]=\sum_{n=k}^\infty np\big[H_k=n\big]\ ,
$$
since clearly $\ p\big[H_k=n\big]=0\ $ for $\ n<k\ .$ But you've also mistakenly assumed that $\ p\big[H_k=n]=p\big[X_n=k\big]\ ,$ which isn't true.  In fact $\ H_k=n\ $ if and only if $\ X_{n-1}= k-1\ $ and the $\ n^\text{th}\ $ toss is heads. Therefore
\begin{align}
p\big[H_k= n]&=pp\big[X_{n-1}=k-1\big]\\
&={n-1\choose k-1}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\ ,
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
E\big[H_k\big]&=p^k\sum_{n=k}^\infty n{n-1\choose k-1}(1-p)^{n-k}\\
&=p^k\sum_{j=0}^\infty (j+k){j+k-1\choose k-1}(1-p)^j\\
&=kp^k\sum_{j=0}^\infty {j+k\choose k}(1-p)^j\ .\tag{1}\label{e1}
\end{align}
Now $\ \sum_\limits{j=0}^\infty {j+k\choose k}x^j\ $ is the Taylor expansion of the function $\ (1-x)^{-(k+1)}\ $ about $\ x=0\ ,$ which converges to that function for $\ |x|<1\ .$ Therefore, the expression \eqref{e1} for $\ E\big[H_k\big]\ $ reduces to
\begin{align}
E\big[H_k\big]&=kp^k\big(1-(1-p)\big)^{-(k+1)}\\
&=\frac{k}{p}\ .
\end{align}
